# Pip Install keeps installing libraries to Python2.7 rather than Python3

Tags: python, ubuntu, terminal

I'm trying to install modules such as `gitpython` into my `Python3` directory however when I run:
`Pip install gitpython` it automatically downloads it into `python2.7`

I've tried specify the Python3 directory but it says the the library has already been installed.

```
Requirement already satisfied: gitpython in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (2.1.11)
```

Problem is when I try to call `from git import repo` my Python3 can't find the module.

Is there anyway to get pip to install my libraries to Python3 as a default, can I just uninstall Python 2.7 to save problems?

I run
`sudo apt install python3-pip` 
and it states it is already installed, so I run `sudo pip3 install gitpython` and it says `Command 'pip3' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install python3-pip`

**SOLUTION**

`sudo apt-get remove python3-pip; sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

Answer (score 0):

It depends of your version of pip. But I think that python3-pip may do  the trick.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install MODULE_NAME
```

Comment: Well it said I already had python3-pip install, then when I called pip3 it says command not found

Comment: I don't know what I can do to help you,
but does this link help?
https://superuser.com/questions/769920/python3-pip-installed-but-pip3-command-not-found

Comment: Did it solve your problem? A follow up would be appreciated

Comment: I posted a follow up in my Question 20 minutes ago, looks like the question you linked was the same answer as a user gave me in a comment below that I read first.

Answer (score 0):

You should use pip3 to install your packages in your python3 environment. thus instead of installing with pip use `pip3 install gitpython`

Comment: I can't work it out. I run sudo apt get python3-pip and it says already installed. I then run pip3 install gitpython and it says I can install pip3 by that first command I tried

Comment: Maybe you can remove your pip3 install and reinstall pip3 with :
sudo apt-get remove python3-pip 
sudo apt-get install python3-pip

Answer (score 0):

You can try to see the version of python with:

```
python --version
```

if the result is python 2.7, that means that your environment variable for python3 needs to be set.

After that you can try:

```
python -m pip install package_name
```

I hope it will help you =)

Adrien

Answer (score 0):

You should use python3 venv [Python 3 venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

```
python3 -m venv /path/virtual/environment
source /path/virtual/environment/bin/activate
```

or use pip3 to installing any libraries for python 3

```
$ pip3 install 'some library'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create virtual environment for python3. using:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 <VIRTUAL_ENV NAME>
```

Then activate it using:

```
source  <VIRTUAL_ENV NAME>/bin/activate
```

Then install your dependency(gitpython in your case) into that.